# how to compile linux kernel module with -ggdb flag

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I modify my module Makefile to make `kernel` module with `-ggdb` flag,

```
KERNROOT := /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build

ccflags-y += -ggdb3

#ccflags-y += -g

test:

        $(MAKE) $(ccflags-y) -C $(KERNROOT) M=$(shell pwd)
```

But it didn't work. The fail message:

```
make: invalid option -- 'g'

make: invalid option -- 'g'

make: invalid option -- '3'

Usage: make [options] [target] ..
```

.

Any help? Thanks a lot.

Comment: `make CONFIG_DEBUG_INFO=y`

Answer (score 0):

try enabling it through .config file, configurations are taken from there even for compiling the external modules. [you can also refer from here](http://landley.net/kdocs/Documentation/DocBook/xhtml-nochunks/kgdb.html) you can also enable it from

make menuconfig > Kernel Hacking > Compile kernel with debug info

[some reference](http://sateeshkg.blogspot.in/p/kgdb-setup.html) | [some more reference](https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/people/jwessel/kdb/EnableKGDB.html) | [kernel doc regarding gdb](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/gdb-kernel-debugging.txt) | [kernel reference for gdb](https://www.kernel.org/doc/htmldocs/kgdb/EnableKGDB.html)

Answer (score 0):

When calling make, put `KCFLAGS=-ggdb3` prior to any target you're using. For example, to make vmlinux, modules, and bzImage with ggdb3 symbols enabled, run `make KCFLAGS=-ggdb3 all`.

Note that this is NOT the same as just enabling kernel debug symbols as described in the other answer. The -ggdb3 flag adds additional information to the symbol file that is not included by default (such as macro definitions).